# Cannot get irssi to work on Bluehost dedicated IP address

Tags: bluehost, irssi

I am trying to get irssi to work over SSH on my [Bluehost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluehost) dedicated IP server.

Bluehost support says port 6667 is open, but you have to have an app listening to it, so running `nc -l` on the server and then telnet'ing in works, but if I run irssi on the server then it can't connect to *freenode.net* - it says the connection timed out.

If you do `nmap -v -sT` then you see the 6667/TCP port, but it's listed as closed.

How can get irssi to run using an `ssh` shell on Bluehost?

It Would be great to have under a [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session you could re-login to from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you ask them if 6667 is open outbound [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).

Sometimes they can mistake it for inbound or only open TCP for example. You can telnet to your IRC host on port 6667 even if something is not listening on the Bluehost side, assuming IRC is up and accepting connections, and Bluehost has the port opened, a telnet from your Bluehost  account to the IRC server will work fine.